# jQuery get data from jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am using ajax to get the data from the database. After getting data from table I am doing json_encode to get the data in json format. After that I am doing parseJSON to show the data in js.

when I am getting the data in json I just did

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);

console.log(data);
```

I got the data like this jQuery object.

[image]

From here I want to get the values of firstname.

I tried console.log(data.first_name);
but it not worked. It is showing undefined in the console tab. So can someone tell me how to get the first_name value here

Answer (score 1):

Your data is array of objects and has data on indexes 0,1,2 so on so you need

try

```
console.log(data[0].first_name);
```

you can also loop through them

```
for(var a=0;a<data.length;a++) {
    console.log(data[a].first_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been returned an array of objects. Iterate through all of them using:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].first_name);
}
```

Comment: no, do _not_ use `for .. in` on arrays, that's for object keys.

Answer (score 0):

jquery provide [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate object or array, see below sample code

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(data, function(index, object){
  console.log(object.first_name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `data` is array of objects you have to iterate over this array and get the first_name attribute of each object in it as follows,

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
data.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item.first_name);
})
```